# Performance-testing a heap memory manager

Tags: c++, performance, memory-management, heap-memory

I have a memory manager that I would like to compare against other memory managers, both in terms of performance (e.g. speed, overhead, whatever is useful) and in terms of stress (e.g. fragmentation).

How would one write a meaningful benchmark to compare the performance of one memory manager against another?

As an example, I can imagine randomly allocating and deallocating blocks of gradually increasing sizes as shown in the code below, testing to see how long it takes to allocate more memory blocks.
However, I'm not sure if a test like this would be meaningful. Where would I go from here?

```
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
unsigned int rand_uint()
{
    return (static_cast<unsigned int>(rand()) << (0 * sizeof(unsigned short) * CHAR_BIT)) ^
           (static_cast<unsigned int>(rand()) << (1 * sizeof(unsigned short) * CHAR_BIT));
}
int main()
{
    typedef std::vector<char> V;
    V::allocator_type alloc;
    std::vector<std::pair<V::value_type *, size_t> > v(0x12000);
    clock_t start = clock(), prev = start;
    for (size_t n = 0, n_prev = n, m = 0;; ++n, ++m)
    {
        std::pair<V::value_type *, size_t> new_buf(NULL, static_cast<size_t>(pow(m, 0.7)));
        new_buf.first = alloc.allocate(new_buf.second);
        using std::swap; swap(new_buf, v[rand_uint() % v.size()]);
        if (new_buf.first) { alloc.deallocate(new_buf.first, new_buf.second); }
        clock_t const now = clock();
        if (now >= prev + CLOCKS_PER_SEC * 1 / 4)
        {
            std::cerr << "n = " << n << "; at "
                << (n - n_prev) * CLOCKS_PER_SEC / (now - prev + 1)
                << " allocations/second" << std::endl;
            prev = now;
            n_prev = n;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Lazin: I appreciate the revision, but I really don't want to reinvent the wheel if it already exists... that's why I asked if such a benchmark already exists.

Comment: I don't think that such generic benchmarking suite for memory managers are exists or even possible. Didn't hear about anything like that.

Comment: @Lazin: Hmm but then how are memory managers benchmarked and compared against each other? Does people all write their own benchmarks?

Comment: Yes. It's impossible to know fragmentation (internal or external) without some support from memory manager itself (some internal instrumentation mechanism). Different memory managers can be compared with each other in a generic way only by speed of execution, you allocate some memory and than - free it, or allocate in one thread and than free in another (very bad case for most modern allocators), measure time and compare.

Comment: @Lazin: Hmm... why would we need internal instrumentation? Can't you just allocate and deallocate memory in some pattern that is likely to cause fragmentation and test how long it takes for available memory to become exhausted? Whichever memory manager fails first is more prone to fragmentation. I can certainly imagine tests like this, I don't see why they would be *impossible* without instrumentation...

Comment: In a modern 64-bit setting nothing will ever fail until there is some physical memory remaining. If you just measure amount of memory used by process and compare it to amount memory allocated by application - you measure nothing because all memory allocators cache memory pages internally, so memory manager can use lot of memory but have little external fragmentation. It is possible to measure something but impossible to reason about results without knowledge of memory manager internals. Maybe the best way is just run your application and measure performance characteristics in both cases?

Comment: Sometimes it is possible to tune your program's data-structures for best fit with your memory manager. For example: buddy system can work really fast and have very little external fragm-n but internal fragm-n is a killer. It is possible to tailor your data-structures to fit with buddy allocator algorithm well without fragmentation at all (if most of your objects have a size that is a power of two).

Comment: @Lazin: I actually had 32-bit systems in mind as the target for the benchmark because of the same reasons you mentioned... what you say makes a lot more sense for 64-bit systems. For 32-bit it seems like it should be easy to create an allocation pattern that shows how resistant a heap allocator is for fragmentation, and I suppose as a starting point it wouldn't hurt to only look at 32-bit systems since those are easier to stress-test.

Comment: Why is a 67.2k gold badge holder using C headers in C++ code? o.O Not to mention this code is barely readable; you don't even have a consistent brace style! C'mon, you can do better

Comment: Question is too broad; requires a chat room.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I have my reasons for using C headers, and I believe my brace styles are completely consistent. Both of them are 100% irrelevant to the question as the question wasn't about coding style, so I'm not going to divert the discussion to explain. And as far as the spacing goes, I was trying to fit everything on one page vertically so that's why the spacing is lacking.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: If you could explain why exactly it's "too broad" that would be helpful. The current close reason makes no sense, but maybe after hearing your reason, "too broad" will.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Look at the conversation that has already ensued about it. This is broad and open-ended and invites a discussion, not a concrete technical answer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Well, it looks like the people who closed the question didn't agree with your reason, and there are at least 4 people so far who think the question is worth re-opening. If you wouldn't mind, I suggest you hold off on your close vote when the question is reopened to see whether the question will actually get good answers. I suspect it will.

Comment: I've found this paper about dynamic memory allocation benchmarking - http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2491894.2464161&coll=DL&dl=GUIDE&CFID=475655116&CFTOKEN=51321950 This paper has workload model and test descriptions - http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1167999.1168012&coll=DL&dl=GUIDE&CFID=475655116&CFTOKEN=51321950 UPD: both can be found with google scholar, for free.

Comment: @Lazin: Thanks, those papers look useful -- especially page 4 on the second one.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Getting good answers does not make a question on-topic, as you know.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: My brain doesn't work in binary, but it seems like yours does, so go ahead and give yourself the intense pleasure of close the question. Oh wait, looks like you probably already did.

Comment: -1. Performance testing of a heap manager is nothing special. Heap manager is just a library with a few API functions, e.g. `alloc` and `free`. Testing it doesn't differ from testing any other library. You take an application, run it and measure time/memory. Also your code is awful. More than that, `clock` has very bad precision, it's the worst choice for measuring time.

Comment: @Abyx: Writing a good benchmark is hard, it most definitely *is* something special. And if you even *tried* running the code then you would see the precision of `clock` (which, by the way, is 1 ms on my Windows machine, which is good enough for me) is irrelevant given how long it takes the code to run to produce meaningful output. Heck, the clock is only even relevant for testing speed, not stability or fragmentation. Looks like you missed half the point of the benchmark. Still, I do appreciate that you left a comment explaining the downvote...

Comment: @Mehrdad: No need to cry about it! I don't make the rules.

Comment: Probably your best bet is to take some existing C++ project that is heavy on heap allocations and very stable in runtime, and use that as a benchmark. That is probably the most realistic you can get.